# id selector using array notation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of element ids that are randomly generated. The elements already exist, I am not creating or removing them. I just need to select random ones via their id:

stripped out HTML:

```
<div id="circle1"></div>
<div id="circle2"></div>
<button id="start">Start<button>
```

some simple JS/jQuery:

```
var circles = [];

function getRandomCircle() {
    return "circle" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
}

function flashCircles() {
  for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#" + circles[i]).fadeTo("slow", 1, function() {
        $("#" + circles[i]).fadeTo("slow", 0.5, function() {});
      });
    }, i * 1000);
  }
}

$("#start").on("click", function() {
  circles.push(getRandomCircle());
  circles.push(getRandomCircle());
  circles.push(getRandomCircle());
  flashCircles();
});
```

The #circle elements are not getting selected, and thus not fading in and out. I reach the `setTimeout()` call, I don't get inside the callback for the initial selector. The `circles.push(getRandomCircle())` calls work as expected. Nothing changes if I remove them and initialise the circles array instead. I don't think it's the array notation because if I run the following after `setTimeout()` and within the loop, the elements are selected as expected:

```
if ($("#" + circles[i]).length) {
  console.log("selected")
} else {
  console.log("not selected")
}
```

The only thing that works is a hard coding the id to call:

```
 $("#"+"circle1").doStuff();
```

I had this working, originally. `getRandomCircle()` contained a for-loop that populated the array. Nothing else has changed.

What's happening here? Array notation worked before, it works here when checking if something is selected, but it not working within `setTimeout()`, despite the fact it was working before. All code is wrapped in a `$("document").ready()` call.

Comment: Have you tried passing `circles` to your `flashCircles` as a parameter? Or even using `i` in your for loop as a parameter in your `setTimeout` function? I think it even makes sense not to declare `circles` outside your click event handler for encapsulation purposes

Comment: Try logging your 'i' value. You might have an async issue.

Comment: Also why is there no i++ in the forloop?

Comment: the counter has been logged. There is an i++, and no syntax error on my part, just rushed when asking my question. edited the original post.